# Google App Engine and domain name

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain, google-apps

Here is the situation:

I own a Google Apps for Business account.

I have two domain names registered :

- mycompany.com which is the principal domain
- myapp.com which is another domain

Note: both domains are validated and active.

I'm working on a Google App Engine web application and I want it to be accessible via *myapp.com* or *www.myapp.com*.

What I've done so far :

- I've added the GAE web application as a service in my Google Apps account.
- I've tried to change the url but *myapp.com* does'nt appear in the dropbox.

This thing starts to drive me mad...

Comment: Actually, I think a simple url redirection may be a better solution. Just 301 redirect myapp.com to www.myapp.com.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible ATM to bind an App Engine application on a *Google Apps Secondary Domain* (sounds like a bug).

But it works fine on *Google Apps Domain Alias*.

- Go to **https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/yourprimarydomain.com/DomainSettingsDomains**
- Click **Add a domain alias or a domain**
- Select **Add a domain alias of yourprimarydomain.com**
- Follow instructions to verify your domain
- Go to your App Engine application dashboard
- Go to **Application Settings**
- Click **Add Domain**
- Type the domain name of your **primary** Google Apps domain (not the alias)
- Click **Add new URL**
- Select your **domain alias** from the dropdown list
- Click **Add**
- You will be asked to add a **CNAME** to **ghs.google.com** in your DNS configuration

That should work.

Comment: I'm having trouble to see the difference between "secondary domain" and "primary domain alias". Btw, I've deleted my secondary domain, added it again as a primary domain alias, and it magically appreared in the "Add new URL" dropdown list. So problem solved and bounty for you. Still, google apps domains thingy looks poorly done.

Comment: Thanks, don't forget to award the bounty :)

Answer (score 3):

google app engine does not allow mapping naked domain. you can use a redirect from myapp.com to www.myapp.com.

"Due to recent changes, App Engine no longer supports mapping your app to a naked domain. If your domain registrar supports URL redirects, you can redirect from http://yourdomain.com to e.g http://www.yourdomain.com or http://appid.yourdomain.com."

http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/general.html#naked_domain

Comment: Naked or not isn't the real problem. I just want to bind a domain to my GAE app which is not my principal Google Apps domain.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, naked domains ( example.com ) are not supported by App Engine.

Instead you can make a **Web Forward** from **example.com** to **www.example.com**. This can be achieved in various ways  depending on where you've registered your domain and if the registrar offers DNS services.

**If not**, you can use Zoneedit:

1. Sign up for a free account at **[zoneedit.com](http://zoneedit.com)**
2. Create a zone for your website
3. At your domain registrar, change the name servers to **nsXX.zoneedit.com** (multiple nameservers - these addresses can be found the page of your zone)
   [image: zoneedit nameserversenter image description here]
4. Create an alias for your **www** subdomain that maps to **ghs.google.com**
5. To make your site accessible from the naked domain, add a **webforwad** from **domain.com** to **www.domain.com**
   [image]
6. Zbang! You've got a working website, that is accessible from both the naked and the www subdomain.

These changes might take some time to propagate

On the google apps page you had to add thee www web-address on the applications settings tab
[image] 
(what in my understanding you already did)

Hope this helps, and if not you, then maybe others :). + zoneedit is a great & free tool for DNS management, and you can also define custom mail forwards and stuff :)

(Ps. the screen shots are taken from a working app engine example site that runs from www.secondhand-extra.ro )

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I'm not looking for setting up a naked primary domain url. My problem is binding an app on a secondary domain url.

Answer (score 0):

At my goog app manage domain front page, I go to domain settings -> add domain alias for www.zzz-zzz-zzz.com. So I added www.zzz-zzz-zzz.org

At my domain registrar, I declare the following redirects:

zzz-zzz-zzz.com -> www.zzz-zzz-zzz.com
zzz-zzz-zzz.org -> www.zzz-zzz-zzz.org

After that the following urls would all go to the same place:

- zzz-zzz-zzz.com
- www.zzz-zzz-zzz.com
- zzz-zzz-zzz.org
- www.zzz-zzz-zzz.org

Comment: What do you mean by "redirect"? HTTP redirect of DNS CNAME entry?

Answer (score 0):

I think the real answer is to be found in Google's **[Limitations for multiple domains](https://support.google.com/a/answer/182081?hl=en)**:

"Custom URLs for accessing Google Apps are available only for the primary domain. The Admin console enables the administrator to set a custom URL for various services. The custom URL applies only for users accessing the services at the primary domain. The same limitation applies to custom web address mapping for a Google Site."

It's quite a severe limitation, since it requires you to open a new Google Apps account for each custom domain you want to register, even if all domains belong to the same organisation.