# Re-mapping an existing alias of my Google App Engine appspot site to a new version

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

A few years ago GAE compelled everyone to migrate their apps from a master-slave datastore to a high-replication one.  When that happened, an alias got created. My old project was named "myapp", the domain of the new project became
"myapp-hrd" and the new URL "myapp-hrd.appspot.com" accesses the new project.  But the old original URL "myapp.appspot.com" also points to it, thus the old URL is now an alias.

I have created a completely new project with a new version of my app, called "myapp-v2".  Is there a way to redirect the existing "myapp.appspot.com" alias from the hrd app to the new v2 one?  I could start using the new "myapp-v2.appspot.com" URL instead, but that's ugly, and I prefer to keep the old URL. I thought that there would be an easy way to modify the aliases using the Google Cloud Platform console, but if there is, I'm not finding it.

I could register a new domain, point it at the new one, and start using that, but my preference would be to be able to keep on using the same URL I always have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [Community Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6571183/12857703), you are going to have to use Google Apps Domain Alias to do that, you will have to follow these steps:

- Go to https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/myapp-hrd.appspot.com/DomainSettingsDomains
- Remove the "myapp.appspot.com" domain alias of that domain

That being done you freed up your alias from the first project's domain. Now you have to do the following for the second project:

- Go to https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/myapp-v2.appspot.com/DomainSettingsDomains
- Click Add a domain alias or a domain
- Select Add a domain alias of myapp-hrd.appspot.com
- Follow instructions to verify your domain (if needed)

Now you have to setup the alias at the App Engine configuration:

- Go to your App Engine application dashboard
- Go to Application Settings
- Click Add Domain
- Type the domain name of your primary Google Apps domain (in that case myapp-v2.appspot.com)
- Click Add new URL
- Select your domain alias from the dropdown list
- Click Add
- You will be asked to add a CNAME to ghs.google.com in your DNS configuration